# Is there a keyboard shortcut to copy down a formula in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

[image: This is what I mean.] An Excel table, there's a little blue and grey icon which pops up and asks if I want to overwrite all the cells in this column with this formula, which I pretty much always do. Can I do it without using the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control D. It doesn't give you all the options, but it fills down.